# Connecting raspberry pi bluetooth app to GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I have a bluetooth script that allows me to stream music from my phone to my raspberry pi in the car. I am trying to create a GUI that allows me to change music via buttons on the screen. At present i can change music by typing the command into the console (prev, pause,play, next) but i would like to use a GUI with onscreen buttons

**The problem**

I am having trouble connecting my gui to the main app. The gui displays then i get no output on the music or the music works but does not display a GUI

**I have tried**

I have tried building the GUI using Tkinter and guizero ( I am new to GUIs) but i get the same problem as above.
I have also tried building and running the gui and the bluetooth script simultaneously and having the GUI print commands to the console but that has also not worked

**CODE for bluetooth**

```
import dbus, dbus.mainloop.glib, sys
from gi.repository import GLib

def on_property_changed(interface, changed, invalidated):
    if interface != 'org.bluez.MediaPlayer1':
        return
    for prop, value in changed.iteritems():
        if prop == 'Status':
            print('Playback Status: {}'.format(value))
        elif prop == 'Track':
            print('Music Info:')
            for key in ('Title', 'Artist', 'Album'):
                print('   {}: {}'.format(key, value.get(key, '')))

def on_playback_control(fd, condition):
    str = fd.readline()
    if str.startswith('play'):
        player_iface.Play()
    elif str.startswith('pause'):
        player_iface.Pause()
    elif str.startswith('next'):
        player_iface.Next()
    elif str.startswith('prev'):
        player_iface.Previous()
    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dbus.mainloop.glib.DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
    bus = dbus.SystemBus()
    obj = bus.get_object('org.bluez', "/")
    mgr = dbus.Interface(obj, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager')
    for path, ifaces in mgr.GetManagedObjects().iteritems():
        adapter = ifaces.get('org.bluez.MediaPlayer1')
        if not adapter:
            continue
        player = bus.get_object('org.bluez',path)
        player_iface = dbus.Interface(
                player,
                dbus_interface='org.bluez.MediaPlayer1')
        break
    if not adapter:
        sys.exit('Error: Media Player not found.')

    bus.add_signal_receiver(
            on_property_changed,
            bus_name='org.bluez',
            signal_name='PropertiesChanged',
            dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties')
    GLib.io_add_watch(sys.stdin, GLib.IO_IN, on_playback_control)
    GLib.MainLoop().run()
```

**CODE FOR Simple GUI using guizero**

```
from guizero import App, PushButton

app = App()

def prev():
    print("prev")

prev_button = PushButton(app, command=prev, text="PREV")

app.display()
```

---

Bluetooth code source
https://scribles.net/controlling-bluetooth-audio-on-raspberry-pi/

Comment: it seems main problem is that both have own event loop - `mainloop()` and `display()` - which blocks all code. I' wandering what if you skip `mainloop().run()` and use directly `command=player_iface.Previous`

Comment: I have tried not and it produces the error player_iface not defined

Comment: I did some tweeking. I needed to add all the code except for the GLib. Mainloop(). Run() into the gui script. That allowed me to call player_iface methods